# Validation error while filling up the form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set validation custom error when wrong input is beeing passed.

this is my form written with help of thymeleaf template:

```
<form th:action="@{/addPet}" th:object="${petDto}" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pet name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{pet.petName}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pet.petName')}" th:errors="*{pet.petName}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Owner First name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{owner.firstName}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('owner.firstName')}" th:errors="*{owner.firstName}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Owner Last name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{owner.lastName}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('owner.lastName')}" th:errors="*{owner.lastName">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Owner Number:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{owner.phoneNumber}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('owner.phoneNumber')}" th:errors="*{owner.phoneNumber}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="add" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

So there is dto passed containing two fields:

```
public class PetDto {


    private Pet pet;
    private Owner owner;
```

Now when I enter wrong input I'm getting this:

```
here was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Validation failed for classes [pl.kaczynski.model.Owner] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Length must be between 2 and 15 characters.', propertyPath=lastName, rootBeanClass=class pl.kaczynski.model.Owner, messageTemplate='{Size}'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Length must be between 2 and 15 characters.', propertyPath=firstName, rootBeanClass=class pl.kaczynski.model.Owner, messageTemplate='{Size}'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='numeric value out of bounds (<9 digits>.<0 digits> expected)', propertyPath=phoneNumber, rootBeanClass=class pl.kaczynski.model.Owner, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Digits.message}'} ]
```

And my goal is have to error message displayed next to the input fields in the same view, not redirecting to error page. I have made similiar form pages for objects Pet and Owner, and there it works fine, which makes me thinking that there is a problem with my composition class DTO.

edit// 
this is model class:

```
@Entity
public class Pet extends BaseClass{

    @Column(name = "pet_name")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    private String petName;
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_Id")
    private Owner owner;

@Entity
public class Owner extends BaseClass {

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 15, message = "{Size}")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 15, message = "{Size}")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 9)
    private String phoneNumber;
```

And here is controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPetPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="petDto") PetDto petDto, BindingResult result){

        if(result.hasErrors())
            return "/addPet";

        Owner owner = petDto.getOwner();
        Pet pet = petDto.getPet();
        pet.setOwner(owner);

        ownerService.add(owner);
        petService.add(pet);
        return "redirect:addPet";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
<tr>
    <td>Pet name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{pet.petName}" /></td>
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pet.petName')}">
        <ul>
            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('pet.firstName')}" th:text="${err}">error text</li>
        <ul>
    </span>
</tr>
```

If you have several error messages for the same field (like *First Name is required*, *First Name must have 2 to 15 characters* etc) they will be printed in a list.

Comment: this is not working, I think the problem might be with BindingResult result object, because I debugged it, and the  if(result.hasErrors()) is not true, and the flow goes further so the whitelabel page error from spring boot kicks in. So the goal is now to make the result see the error

Comment: what would You like to have?

Comment: I think your error is here `if(result.hasErrors()) return "/addPet";`. You must return the same form, something like `return "petForm";` or how you named it.

Comment: code does not get to get there so basically it does no matter what's there hence the work flow skips it